# Can I conditionally add a where() clause to my knex query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I want to add a `where()` clause in my query, but **conditionally**. Specifically, I want it added only if a sepecific querystring parameter is passed in the URL. Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about doing it?

```
router.get('/questions', function (req, res) {
    knex('questions')
        .select('question', 'correct', 'incorrect')
        .limit(50)
        .where('somecolumn', req.query.param) // <-- only if param exists
        .then(function (results) {
            res.send(results);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can store your query in a variable, apply your conditional where clause and then execute it, like this :

```
router.get('/questions', function(req, res) {
  var query = knex('questions')
              .select('question', 'correct', 'incorrect')
              .limit(50);

  if(req.query.param == some_condition)
    query.where('somecolumn', req.query.param) // <-- only if param exists
  else
    query.where('somecolumn', req.query.param2) // <-- for instance

  query.then(function(results) {
    //query success
    res.send(results);
  })
  .then(null, function(err) {
    //query fail
    res.status(500).send(err);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please also check the other anwer!

Comment: Can I ask why this is less upvoted? Is there a specific downside to this method? Because it seems much cleaner and allows for use of `await`.

Comment: @bzupnick the `.modify()` construction keeps you entirely within knex's provided Query Builder API, which seems cleaner than going "off road" with a JavaScript workaround. The knex docs state that `modify()` "Allows encapsulating and re-using query snippets and common behaviors as functions." Since you mention `await` as a desirable feature: The knex query with a `modify` clause is also `await`-able.

Comment: FYI for those using it, this method prevents `knex-paginate` from returning the `pagination` info in the response. If you're using `knex-paginate`, go with the `modify()` method instead.

Answer (score 158):

Yes. Use [modify](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-modify).

As applied to your example:

```
router.get('/questions', function (req, res) {
    knex('questions')
        .select('question', 'correct', 'incorrect')
        .limit(50)
        .modify(function(queryBuilder) {
            if (req.query.param) {
                queryBuilder.where('somecolumn', req.query.param);
            }
        })   
        .then(function (results) {
            res.send(results);
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think it should be:  if (req.query.param) {
                     queryBuilder.where('somecolumn', req.query.param);
                }

Comment: This is the perfect way of doing it. Absolutely should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Much better way than accepted answer! KNEX documentation should add this way of using .modify - to support conditionally applying query features

Comment: How does this work if you want to chain multiple potentials WHERE's on? Say I have 6 params that each could trigger an AND potentially. Or potentially a single WHERE, with any combination

Comment: @eponymous23 please accept this as answer

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use `queryBuilder` inside `.where()` like so:

```
.where((queryBuilder) => {condition === true ? do something if true : do something if false })
```

IMO [@ItaiNoam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36064282/327074) should be the correct one with `.modify()`

Answer (score -1):

Most simplest solution is `skipUndefined`

```
Person.query()
  .skipUndefined()
  .where('firstName', req.query.firstName);
```

Comment: skipUndefined seems not to be defined in the current docs.  I don't know if it's from an older version or if it's an undocumented feature.  If it's the latter could you mention that in your answer?

Answer (score -11):

You can do it by checking if your query string is present and running a different query.

```js
router.get('/questions', function(req, res) {
  if (req.query.yourQueryString) {
    // Run your more specific select
  } else {
    knex('questions').select('question', 'correct', 'incorrect').limit(50).where(
        'somecolumn', req.query.param) // <-- only if param exists
      .then(function(results) {
        res.send(results);
      });
  }
}
});
```