# javascript method chaining - knex.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I'm a PHP Developer and for a new project I decided to use a node.js backend. So I'm quite new to that.

I'm using knex.js to handle my database connection and manipulate the data.
F.ex I have the following query:

```
let gastronomies = await knex
  .from('user')
  .innerJoin('profile', 'user.id', 'profile.user_id')
  .where('user.status', 1);
```

If the client passes an additional variable to the function it should be used as another query param

```
if(args.lat) {
    gastronomies = await knex
    .from('user')
    .innerJoin('profile', 'user.id', 'profile.user_id')
    .where('user.status', 1)
    .where('lat', 'like', args.lat); //there it is
  }
```

I'd like to chain the methods but it is not working at all. This is what I came up with:

```
let gastronomies = await knex
  .from('user')
  .select('*', {key: 'user.id'})
  .innerJoin('profile', 'user.id', 'profile.user_id')
  .where('user.status', 1);

if(args.lat)
    gastronomies.where('lat', 'like', args.lat);
```

But it says that gastronomies does not have a method called "where". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to chain it you should wait with `async/await`, cause it will trigger call to database.
I'd do it like that:

```
const gastronomies = knex // no await here
  .from('user')
  .select('*', {key: 'user.id'})
  .innerJoin('profile', 'user.id', 'profile.user_id')
  .where('user.status', 1);

if(args.lat)
    gastronomies.where('lat', 'like', args.lat);

const response = await gastronomies;
```

You can also check answer to your question with promises here: [Can I conditionally add a where() clause to my knex query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232415/can-i-conditionally-add-a-where-clause-to-my-knex-query)

Comment: Your answer works, thank you! 
I build my query without "await", chain it with with my conditions and after that i just do "return await gastronomies" and it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the docs - you can pass in multiple where clauses using an object:

`.where({
  first_name: 'Test',
  last_name:  'User'
})`

http://knexjs.org/#Builder-where