# Knex Throwing Error When Binding in undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I am using **Nodejs version 12.14.1** and **Knex version 0.20.8**

In [Knex](http://knexjs.org/) documentation they tell if in a where query a binding is undefined knex will throw an error.
Is there a way to ignore or by pass it?

I tried using `"useNullAsDefault": true,` parameter in my knex file, but it doesn't help

**SQL Example**

```
knex('accounts')
  .where('login', undefined)
  .select()
  .toSQL()
```

**ERROR**

**Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT. Undefined column(s): [login] query: select * from `accounts` where `login` = ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can send a function as parameter of [`where`](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-where), they you can just check if your variable is not undefined so you don't generate a `where` without a value to compare:

```
let login = undefined

knex('accounts')
  .where((builder) => {
    if (login) {
      builder.where('login', login)
    }  
  })
  .select()
  .toSQL()
```

---

If `login` is `undefined`, the sql will be:

```sql
select *
```

And if you set `login = 'test'`, the sql will be:

```sql
select * where ("login" = ?)
```

With `test` value in the `bindings`

Comment: any reason why "useNullAsDefault": true property is not working?

Comment: `useNullAsDefault` is for insert query only. It is used to replace the `DEFAULT` value with `NULL` if you don't define a value. So it is not for select query with where clauses.

Comment: ok, is there another way to ignore error instead, this was not present in previous versions of knex 0.14.2

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232415/can-i-conditionally-add-a-where-clause-to-my-knex-query) from which I am basing my answer. You can use the [modify](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-modify) method to conditionally add the where clause when needed.

```
knex('accounts')
  .select()
  .modify(function(queryBuilder) {
      if (req.query.param) {
          queryBuilder.where('login', req.query.param);
      }
   })
   .toSQL()
```

Comment: any reason why "useNullAsDefault": true property is not working?

Comment: I have multiple queries with many where clauses adding a parameter that defines missing binding as null will be very helpful