# How can i use the querystring for knex?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, knex.js

```
router.get("/stocks/symbols", function (req, res, next) {
  req.db
    .from("stocks")
    .select("name","symbol","industry")
    .modify(function(queryBuilder) {
      if (req.query.param) {
          queryBuilder.where('industry',req.query.param);
      }
  })
    .where('timestamp', '=', '2020-03-24T00:00:00Z')
    .then((rows) => {
      res.json(rows)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
      res.json({ Error: false, Message: "Error in MySQL query" })
    })
})
```

I'm trying to make such a functionality to use querystring.
At the moment this runs without error but doesn't do anything.
Whether I put ?industry=h or anything after the route, it returns the same data.
There was an example I followed, but for some reason its not working.
What else am i missing?

```
router.get("/stocks/symbols/:industry", function (req, res, next) {
  req.db
    .from("stocks")
    .select("name","symbol","industry")
    .where('timestamp', '=', '2020-03-24T00:00:00Z')
    .where("industry", "like", `%${req.params.industry}%`)
    .then((rows) => {
      res.json({ Error: false, Message: "Success", Cities: rows })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
      res.json({ Error: true, Message: "Error in MySQL query" })
    })
})
```

This does similar job that i want to do but it doesn't use the querystring.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232415/can-i-conditionally-add-a-where-clause-to-my-knex-query

Comment: this is the similar example I tried to follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the correct query parameter - in your code you use `query.param` meaning that your url would need to contain `/stocks/symbols?param=tbd`

If you're expecting `industry` as a query-param, you need to change it to:

```
.modify(function(queryBuilder) {
      if (req.query.industry) {
          queryBuilder.where('industry',req.query.industry);
      }
  })
```

Comment: Its partly working, but the problem happening right now is that I need to put the exact value to get answer. If I just put "h", it doesn't return anything and if i put "health care"(exact name) it works.

Comment: I solved it using the same method queryBuilder.where('industry',"like",`%${req.query.industry}%`